GitPython unable to execute command in existing repository
I am trying to run a script with GitPython, but it seems to only fail when I run from inside the Jenkins automation environment. The error that it gives isn't very helpful (and I haven't been able to find a solution for it in my searching), so I'm hoping someone here can help.
Here's some data for my setup.

Git version: 2.45.2
python version: 3.12.4 (in a virtual environment)
GitPython module: 3.1.43

Error encountered (proprietary pathnames and other secrets removed):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/auth_tester.py", line 5, in <module>
    repository.remote().pull()
  File "/path/to/pyenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 1123, in pull
    res = self._get_fetch_info_from_stderr(proc, progress, kill_after_timeout=kill_after_timeout)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/pyenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/git/remote.py", line 895, in _get_fetch_info_from_stderr
    proc.wait(stderr=stderr_text)
  File "/path/to/pyenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 834, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(remove_password_if_present(self.args), status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git pull -v -- origin

Sample of the code that causes it (secrets also removed):
import os
from git import Repo

repository = Repo(".")
repository.remote().pull()

Is there an environment variable that might be missing from the Jenkins run, that would be included when I run it locally?

Does git pull -v -- origin work if you run it manually? Do you need authorization to pull from the remote repository? Remember, Jenkins is (probably) running as a different user than you.

I can run it on my own machine just fine. I can also remote into the Jenkins machine and run it there without issue.

Is the repository initially checked out by jenkins ? If yes, jenkins typically makes the initial checkout with detached head and i'd guess doing a git pull on detached head would fail because same commit can be in multiple branches. Another one is what transport should git use ?


Is the repository initially checked out by jenkins ?

It is, by I also ran another command to do "another" checkout, solving the detached head issue.

Another one is what transport should git use ?

I used SSH (and deploy key) for a while, but also tried HTTPS (and a Personal Token) - both transports yielded the same error.
